# Superposition in classical Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, superposition, linear-systems

I watched a video in YouTube solved these problem using superposition 
First he fixed the bottom rope and found the accelearations 
Second he fixed the upper pulley and found the accelerations 
Third he added the results - as we do in solving AC steady state circuits - 
I wondered does it work because Newton's Law is linear? 
can I solve any classical mechanics problems involving many systems by that method or does it have limitations? 
The video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfNsGuR6rVA
[image]

Comment: In general, a superposition of solutions to a *linear differential equation* is also a solution of the equation. See also [Superposition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle).

Comment: i know that im talking about mechanics hee and if i can use it on all problems

Comment: The answer is that no, you can't use it on all problems in classical mechanics; you can only use it on systems that can be described by a linear differential equation.

Comment: If you have a classical system that is described by a nonlinear differential equation, then you can't use the superposition principle.

Comment: ugh. Some nonlinear differential equations retain a Lie group symmetry of solutions, meaning that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are solutions, imply that $G(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ will also be a solution

Comment: @lurscher, interesting, I didn't know that. Is there a general theorem that let's you discern such problems from the nonlinear differential equations without this kind of symmetry?

Comment: Also, is $G(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ any linear function of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, or does the differential equations restrict the form of $G$?

Comment: the simplest approach to derive the group structure from the differential equation is to expand in power series in terms of the nonlinear coeffs. and find the structure constants for each power

Comment: Can you give us examples to non linear mechanics problems ?

Comment: There are many non-linear mechanics examples, you can take another form of the Hook's law as $F=-k_1x+k_2x^2$,and you now longer have a linear equation. Also when you aproximmate the simple pendulum  with $\sin(\theta)\approx\theta$, you can also do it with $\sin(\theta)\approx\theta- \theta^3/6$. We aproximate in physics to make life easier, otherwise we might not be able to compare any phenomena with aour intiuition beacuase of the difficulty of the maths . Also this aproximations are really good and for many systems

Answer (score 1):

Consider the well-known mechanical [harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion), where you combine Newtons 2nd law $F = m\ddot{x}$ for the motion of an object with mass $m$, with [Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) $F = -kx$ for the force from a spring with stiffness $k$. The resulting differential equation is:
$$ m\ddot{x} + kx = 0$$
This is a linear differential equation, because if we add the equation for a position $x_1$ and a position $x_2$, then we obtain an equation of exactly the same form for $x_1+x_2$:
$$ (m\ddot{x}_1 + kx_1) =0\quad\text{and}\quad (m\ddot{x}_2 + kx_2) =0 \\ \Downarrow \\ a(m\ddot{x}_1 + kx_1) + b(m\ddot{x}_x + kx_x) = 0 \\ \Downarrow \\ m(a\ddot{x}_1+b\ddot{x}_2) + k(ax_1+bx_2) = 0$$
This is the source of the superposition principle: any linear combination $ax_1+bx_2$ of two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ to the differential equation, also has to obey the same differential equation. Thus, any superposition of solutions are also solutions.

However, Hooke's law is only valid for relatively small displacements $x$; in general, the force from a deformed material will be a nonlinear function, which varies between different kinds of materials. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law):

> Hooke's law is only a first order linear approximation to the real response of springs and other elastic bodies to applied forces. It must eventually fail once the forces exceed some limit, since no material can be compressed beyond a certain minimum size, or stretched beyond a maximum size, without some permanent deformation or change of state. In fact, many materials will noticeably deviate from Hooke's law well before those elastic limits are reached.

Let us consider such an example. Let's say that we're studying a material where the spring force is $F=-\tanh(kx)$. As you can see from [plotting the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-tanh%28x%29), the hyperbolic tangent behaves nearly linearly for small $x$ and therefore obeys Hooke's law in this region. However, for large positive values of $x$, this force will converge towards $-1$, while for large negative values of $x$ it converges to $+1$. A physical motivation for considering such a spring force, would be that once e.g. a metallic spring is stretched or compressed to a certain threshold, any additional force you apply will simply deform the material, which reduces the spring restoration force. Thus, after a certain threshold, we expect a nearly constant spring force due to the deformation of the material.

Combining $F=m\ddot{x}$ with $F=-C\tanh(kx)$, we obtain the following differential equation:
$$ m\ddot{x} + C\tanh(kx) = 0 $$
This is an example of a nonlinear differential equation. If we try to add the differential equation for two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ like before, [then we would obtain](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+tanh%28x%29+%2B+b+tanh%28y%29):
$$ m(\ddot{x}_1 + \ddot{x}_2) + C(a+b)\frac{e^{2k(x_1+x_2)} - 1}{(e^{2kx}+1)(e^{2ky}+1)} = 0 $$
So we see that in this case, $ax_1+ax_2$ follows an entirely *different* differential equation from $x_1$ and $x_2$, since $a\tanh(kx_1)+b\tanh(kx_2)\neq \tanh(akx_1+bkx_2)$. Therefore the superposition principle does not hold for this kind of system.

Comment: Thanks so that is the reason why his method work ? although i knew before what you wrote but it didn't give me intuition about the example i put , i meant can i consider special cases and add them like he did ?

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics we have $F=m\ddot{x}$, so you tend to get linear differential equations if the forces are linear functions of $x$ and its time derivatives. Typical examples of this in mechanics, are systems that include ideal ropes (which mediate a constant force), linearized gravity (vertical force $F=-mg$), ideal springs (linear force $F=-kx$), and linearized kinetic friction (as in $F = -c\dot{x}$). The example in your figure, seems to include exactly ideal ropes and linearized gravity.